# Javascript - Get LONG* from COM/ActiveX

Tags: javascript, jquery, activex

I'm using an embedded ActiveX media player which I'm calling from JS/JQuery. I can call functions and set properties in the player without issue. However, one of the properties I need from the ActiveX control is a LONG* pointer, which has the signature....

```
get_CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec(LONG* pVal)
```

..and I'm not really sure where to start. I've done some Googling and found some loose references to BSTR in Javascript, but I'm unsure how to implement it. I need an equivilent of an 'out' that I use in C# I suppose. Here is where I am so far...

```
  $("#fooBtn").click(function(){
    var currTime;
    o.get_CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec(currTime);
    $("#fooDiv").text(currTime);
  });
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I hope you are developing e.g. a windows gadget and not something that will only run in the IE browser...

Comment: @ThiefMaster, does it help to solve this specific problem?

Comment: It's a cross browser thing, although restricted to Windows, but for internal comapany use and they are happy with that. Testing in Mozilla and Chrome currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with JavaScript, however you could use a piece of VBScript on the same page which should make it possible. I'm not an expert with VB, but I'll try to find some sample code.

**[UPDATE]**

Try this:

```
<script language="vbscript">
Function GetCurrentPlaybackTime()
    Dim objValue
    call o.get_CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec(objValue)
    GetCurrentPlaybackTime = objValue
End Function
</script>

<script language="javascript">
  $("#fooBtn").click(function(){
    $("#fooDiv").text(GetCurrentPlaybackTime());
  });
</script>
```

**[EDITED]** You did not show the IDL signature of `get_CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec`. If it looks like this: `HRESULT get_CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec([out, retval]LONG* pVal)`, you simply should be able to call it from JavaScript:

```
var currTime = o.get_CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec();
```

if there's no `retval`, VBScript would be required.

Comment: No problem, let us know if it works. Obviously, I could not verify it.

Comment: Note that VBScript will be IE-only.

Comment: Right, same as ActiveX.

Comment: Unsure of the signature. Only details I have on it are [link to API](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcg2r36o41tbmj7/ActiveX%20API.htm) Although I did try the 'normal' method and had no luck.

Comment: Is there any VBScript error message? Sorry, the API link did not help. If you have [OleView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693754(v=vs.85).aspx), you can use it to recreate the signature. OleView is a part of Windows SDK (on my PC, it's here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\oleview.exe").

Comment: You are a star! Looked at it in OleView and found that they'd written the API documentation wrong! The function is just 'CurrentPlaybackTime_Sec' and does indeed have an [out, retval] LONG* pVal. Working a treat now. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote as new to SO and only have 6 rep!